# carousel image not being full width even with min-width:100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

my image in carousel doesn't have a full width. and I want to reduce the height of the carousel that I've decided to upload it here. 
below is my code for the carousel. please any attempt to help will be appreciated. I already tried playing with the height of image.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class='carousel slide' id="myCarousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
<li class="active" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
<li class="active" data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    </ol>


    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active" id="slide1">
            <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/SQ691ZO.jpg"/ >
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>hello</h4>
                <p>hi you</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="item" id="slide2">
                            <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/SQ691ZO.jpg" />

            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>hello</h4>
                <p>hi you</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="item" id="slide3">
                            <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/SQ691ZO.jpg" />

            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>hello</h4>
                <p>hi you</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

<a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are using <img> instead of using background images, so when you see the slide, you basically see the image with dimensions lower than your carousel container width

Comment: @markoffden I tried with background but the image didn\t show. I struggled with that quite a bit actually. you put background in css right?

Comment: Check the posted answer, there is a proper solution: giving your carousel item fixed height and using image as a background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried adding width to img simply it does work, Is this expected behaviour?

```css
.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class='carousel slide' id="myCarousel">

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
      </ol>


      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active" id="slide1">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SQ691ZO.jpg" >
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>hello</h4>
            <p>hi you</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item" id="slide2">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zN4h51m.jpg" >

          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>hello</h4>
            <p>hi you</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item" id="slide3">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/3ruWvoG.jpg">

          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>hello</h4>
            <p>hi you</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>


    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: but problem is the carousel size is being changed depends on the size of the image. is it possible to set the size of the image/carousel being fixed?

Comment: modified snippet, width is 100% for all images, height is fixed 200px;

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your css

```
position: absolute;
background-size: cover;
```

This should fix your issue.

To be more precise,

```
.carousel{
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  left: 0 !important;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: block !important;
  min-height: 500px !important;
  height: 500px !important; /* Height as you want.*/
}
```

No need to specify width.

**UPDATE:**

This is the exact code you need to place. The carousel image should be specified in `background` attr of `CSS` and not in `img` tag

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class='carousel slide' id="myCarousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
<li class="active" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
<li class="active" data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    </ol>


    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active" id="slide1" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/SQ691ZO.jpg)"> 

<!-- Specify the image as background and add the CSS I gave you.-->
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>hello</h4>
                <p>hi you</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="item" id="slide2">
                            <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/SQ691ZO.jpg" />

            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>hello</h4>
                <p>hi you</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="item" id="slide3">
                            <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/SQ691ZO.jpg" />

            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>hello</h4>
                <p>hi you</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

<a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you add the CSS properly?

Comment: thank you but I gotta do what the other solution showed me to do, it works and I understand the code ;) although I know I shouldn't add style directly

Comment: but problem is the carousel size is being changed depends on the size of the image. is it possible to set the size of the image/carousel being fixed?

Comment: Yes, but that is not recommended on other screen sizes. Add `!important` to the height and width. Thats it.!